# How to acces foreign attributes in a select form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the models:

```
class Bloque < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :temporada
end

class Temporada < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bloques
end
```

And the collection_select in a view:

```
<%= collection_select(:bloques, :id, Bloque.all, :id, :temporada, {}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: 'true'}) %>
```

I want the name of temporada in Bloque, as in `:temporada_name`, instead of plain :temporada in the `collection_select`. Because the list appears as:

[image]

and I want the name of the temporadas to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Module#delegate` to delegate `temporada_name` to `temporada.name`.

```
class Bloque < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :temporada
  delegate :name, to: :temporada, prefix: true
end
```

---

```
<%= collection_select(:bloques, :id, Bloque.includes(:temporada).all, :id, :temporada_name, {}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: 'true'}) %>
```

Comment: Yes !! Thanks. I just had to replace .include for .join as`<%= collection_select(:bloques, :id, Bloque.join(:temporada).all, :id, :temporada_name, {}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: 'true'}) %>`

Comment: Not a good idea. The whole point of using `.includes` is to avoid a N+1 query. `.joins` does not actually load the assocation. I realize now that there was a minor typo there. https://scoutapm.com/blog/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where